# Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cwebp_tmp/dwebp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I am trying to use [webp-io](https://github.com/hellokaton/webp-io) in android project

When I invoke the function `WebpIO.create().toNormalImage(src,dest);` it throwing `FileNotFound` exception

The App has read write permission.
and I can see the folder is created named as cwebp_tmp but still exception is `No such file or folder`

```
 Error: reject normal resason :io.github.biezhi.webp.WebpIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cwebp_tmp/dwebp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

```java
public class WebpIO {

    /**
     * cwebp/dwebp/gif2webp
     * <p>
     * binary command file path
     */
    private static final String OS_NAME  = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    private static final String OS_ARCH  = System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase();
    private static final String DEV_MODE = System.getProperty("webp-io.devMode", "false");

    private String commandDir;
    private String webpTmpDir = "cwebp_tmp";

    public WebpIO() {
        this.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        String osName   = getOsName();
        String webpPath = "cwebp/" + osName;

        if (Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals(DEV_MODE.toUpperCase())) {
            this.commandDir = WebpIO.class.getResource("/").getPath() + webpPath;
            return;
        }

        // copy to tmp dir
        File tmp = new File(webpTmpDir);
        if (!tmp.exists()) {
            tmp.mkdirs();
        }

        this.commandDir = tmp.getPath();

        String extension = getExtensionByOs(osName);

        InputStream dwebp    = getInputStream("/" + webpPath + "/dwebp" + extension);
        InputStream cwebp    = getInputStream("/" + webpPath + "/cwebp" + extension);
        InputStream gif2webp = getInputStream("/" + webpPath + "/gif2webp" + extension);

        try {
            copy(dwebp, new File(tmp.getPath() + "/dwebp" + extension));
            copy(cwebp, new File(tmp.getPath() + "/cwebp" + extension));
            copy(gif2webp, new File(tmp.getPath() + "/gif2webp" + extension));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebpIOException(e);
        }
    }

    public static WebpIO create() {
        return new WebpIO();
    }

    private InputStream getInputStream(String subPath) {
        return WebpIO.class.getResourceAsStream(subPath);
    }

    /**
     * Converter webp file to normal image
     *
     * @param src  webp file path
     * @param dest normal image path
     */
    public void toNormalImage(String src, String dest) {
        toNormalImage(new File(src), new File(dest));
    }

    /**
     * Converter webp file to normal image
     *
     * @param src  webp file path
     * @param dest normal image path
     */
    public void toNormalImage(File src, File dest) {
        String command = commandDir + (dest.getName().endsWith(".gif") ? "/gif2webp" : "/dwebp ") + src.getPath() + " -o " + dest.getPath();
        this.executeCommand(command);
    }

    /**
     * Convert normal image to webp file
     *
     * @param src  nomal image path
     * @param dest webp file path
     */
    public void toWEBP(String src, String dest) {
        toWEBP(new File(src), new File(dest));
    }

    /**
     * Convert normal image to webp file
     *
     * @param src  nomal image path
     * @param dest webp file path
     */
    public void toWEBP(File src, File dest) {
        try {
            String command = commandDir + (src.getName().endsWith(".gif") ? "/gif2webp " : "/cwebp ") + src.getPath() + " -o " + dest.getPath();
            this.executeCommand(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebpIOException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * execute command
     *
     * @param command command direct
     * @return
     */
    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        System.out.println("Execute: " + command);

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Process       p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String         line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebpIOException(e);
        }
        if (!"".equals(output.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + output);
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * delete temp dir and commands
     */
    public void close() {
        File tmp = new File(webpTmpDir);
        if (tmp.exists() && tmp.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = tmp.listFiles();
            for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(files)) {
                file.delete();
            }
            tmp.delete();
        }
    }

    private void copy(InputStream in, File dest) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out    = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[]       buffer = new byte[1024];
        int          length;
        //copy the file content in bytes
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        dest.setExecutable(true);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * get os name and arch
     *
     * @return
     */
    private String getOsName() {
        // windows
        if (OS_NAME.contains("win")) {
            boolean is64bit = (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
            return "windows_" + (is64bit ? "x86_64" : "x86");
        } else if (OS_NAME.contains("mac")) {
            // mac osx
            return "mac_" + OS_ARCH;
        } else if (OS_NAME.contains("nix") || OS_NAME.contains("nux") || OS_NAME.indexOf("aix") > 0) {
            // unix
            return "amd64".equalsIgnoreCase(OS_ARCH) ? "linux_x86_64" : "linux_" + OS_ARCH;
        } else {
            throw new WebpIOException("Hi boy, Your OS is not support!!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the Os specific extension
     *
     * @param os: operating system name
     */
    private String getExtensionByOs(String os) {
        if (os == null || os.isEmpty()) return "";
        else if (os.contains("win")) return ".exe";
        return "";
    }

}
```

Configs

.gradle

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.biezhi/webp-io
    implementation 'io.github.biezhi:webp-io:0.0.5'
```

.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <provider
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        ...
```

You can check the folders structure of tools cweb dweb gif2webp [here](https://github.com/hellokaton/webp-io/tree/master/src/main/resources/cwebp)
The developer is inactive on this repo. I have no idea how to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (!tmp.exists()) {
            tmp.mkdirs();
        }` You mean: `if (!tmp.exists()) {
            if(!tmp.mkdirs() return;
        }`

Comment: the folder cwebp_tmp is being created but still the exception is being raised.

Comment: We cannot see with which parameter values you call that function. Further you did not tell absolute path of created folder.

Comment: btw thank you for responding. Well function take source and destination path. Using those paths to process images using cwebp/dwebp/gif2webp tool  https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/dwebp . which should be temporary copied to temp folder and from there the command will be executed using execute function.

Comment: IF you are android developer can you confirm that the error won't be due to usage of this instead of context here? as we can see dev has used this.init in constructor and the folder is being created but could not access. I am not sure if this is due to context. I am trying to include context in this package.

Comment: You did not tell the values of source and destination path although i asked for them. Further you did not tell full path of directory. Also that was asked.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download is the path for src and dest but that is not used yet the code is stuck at using the tool first. the image path are parameter to be passed to the cwebp/dwebp/gif2webp tool. So first it should access the tool.

Comment: and if(!tmp.mkdirs() executing all time

Comment: You mean that the directory never gets created? Well then start with that problem. But .. you said earlier `the folder cwebp_tmp is being created` So what can we believe?

Comment: yes that folder being created but still !tmp.mkdirs() is true and not only that !tmp.exists() return true as well

Comment: mkdirs() is only called if the directory does not exist yet. So how can you say that the directory exists when it is always called? The directory is never created i would think thats why mkdirs() returns false.

Comment: `!tmp.exists() return true as well` Strange and confusing way of talking. Better:  tmp.exists() returns false.

Comment: Ok this line throws the exceptions ```copy(dwebp, new File(tmp.getPath() + "/dwebp" + extension));```

Comment: If you dont tell value of all those paths then how would we know what you are doing? And does it have to do something with the directory you cannot create? Dont let us guess all.

Comment: `File tmp = new File(webpTmpDir)` My god .. you use only a folder name where the File class expects a full path. No wonder exists() returns false and mkdirs() too as it needs a full path. How could you ever tell us that the directory is created?

Comment: I think once I created the folder manually and assumed that it created by code. I removed that and yeah now not creating directories. my bad. The main cause is creating the directory.